# Writing a file in python in a key=value1,....valuen format

Tags: python

I have a existing file /tmp/ps/snaps.txt 
It has following data:

```
key=default_value
```

I want the contents of this file to be:

```
key=default_value,value,value.....valuen
```

My code for this is (This runs everytime the main python code runs):

```
with open("/tmp/ps/snaps.txt", "a+") as text_file:
    text_file.write("value")
```

But the output I get is :

```
key=default_value,
value,value.....value
```

Basically I dont want my values written on the next line, 
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: What you need to is load the file contents in a suitable data structure, insert the new values and write that data to file again, you should not try to change the contents of the file in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line-terminator at the end of the original file is preventing you from appending on the same line.

You have 3 options:

1. remove that line terminator: your code will work as-is
2. open file in append mode as you do, seek back past the linefeed, and write from there (putting a linefeed for the next time or last char(s) will be overwritten:

code:

```
with open(filename, "a+") as text_file:
    text_file.seek(os.path.getsize(filename)-len(os.linesep))
    text_file.write("{},\n".format(snapshot_name))
```

3. read the file fully, strip the last linefeed (using `str.rstrip()`) and write the contents + the extra contents. The stablest option if you can afford the memory+read overhead for the existing contents.

code:

```
with open(filename,"r") as text_file:
    contents = text_file.read().rstrip()
with open(filename,"w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(contents)
    text_file.write("{},".format(snapshot_name))
```

option 2 is a hack because it tries to edit a text file in read/write, not very good, but demonstrates that it can be done.